# HTML Active Directory Integration

Tags: html, authentication, active-directory

I've created a base login page for an intranet site I'm building and we're no longer able to use passwords from a stored database so I need to integrate AD authentication instead.

How would I be able to do this as the sign-in page has been built in HTML.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It depends what framework you're using, and which web server you're using.